# How to add AWS Cognito sub UUID to Sequelize table as primary key?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, amazon-cognito, sequelize-cli

I've been getting a lot of problems trying to add my Cognito user sub UUID into my Sequelize table. I have seen solutions for Sequelize to auto-generate their own UUID but not for custom ones? I am pushing the AWS sub UUID from my client-side as a payload in express.

Model file:

```
function User(sequelize) {
  const User = sequelize.define(
    "User",
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
```

Client Side

```
      console.log('result: ', user);
      console.log('result: ', user.userSub, typeof user.userSub);
      console.log('uuid result: ', uuidParse(user.userSub), typeof uuidParse(user.userSub));

      let payload = {
        id: user.userSub,
        username: username,
        email: email,
        birthday: birthdate
      }

      const request = {
        url: `/api/user`,
        method: 'POST',
        payload,
      };

      query(request);
```

Error:

```
"name":"SequelizeValidationError","errors":[{"message":"User.id cannot be null","type":"notNull Violation","path":"id","value":null,"origin":"CORE"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, it seems I forget to add id in my parameter in my createUser method in my model. Everything is working fine

```
 User.createUser = async function ({ **id**, username, email, bio, birthday, gender }) {
    return await this.create({
      **id**,
      username,
      email,
      bio,
      birthday,
      gender
    });
  };
```